# How to setup shared limits for a set of users in cgroup?

Tags: centos, systemd, cgroups, resources

In work we have centos server where we can connect and give it things to run. Every now and then someone manages to hog all the resources of the server (either cpu or memory) and everything freezes up, so someone has to go there and press the power button. I would like to use cgroups to stop this from happening.

Can I set collective limits for all humans? I mean that if I create a group `humans` and add there all the human users, can I set limits that apply to all the processes these users run collectively? Say that I don't want all these processes to get more than 30Gb of memory and 90% of cpu (soft limit). How can I declare this?

Also a connected question. What is the default cpu shares? I mean that if I set cpu shares to 512 for a user, what percentage is this assuming that I define nothing else?